# wxHaskell: convert Data.ByteString to Image

Tags: haskell, bytestring, wxhaskell

I have some raw data that represents an image as `Data.ByteString`. Is there a way in wxHaskell to convert it to an image/bitemap?

This raw data can be an image like PNG/JPG/GIF, so it will start with byte sequences like "PNG etc".

I tried to use "gd-3000" to create it, but I wasn't able to make "compatible" the output of that library with wx.

Comment: What's in the ByteString? Raw pixel values, or something like the contents of a PNG file?

Comment: I have re-edited the question. Please look at it.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no function to read such data from a ByteString, but there are functions to read images/bitmaps from file, see imageCreateFromFile and bitmapCreateFromFile from [Graphics.UI.WX.Media](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wx-0.92.1.0/docs/Graphics-UI-WX-Media.html). (If necessary, you could use a temporary file for these functions.)